# Scale image down to fit on mobile devices is not working

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I have an company's employee team page I am working on [HERE.](http://texasca.com/team)

My problem is that the employee's images will not scale down when they appear on mobile.

My CSS is like this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .employee-image {
        max-width: 85%;
        max-height: 85%;
    }
}
```

Maybe I have conflicting CSS somewhere? I do not know.

Page link: http://texasca.com/team

CSS Link: http://texasca.com/includes/team.css

Comment: Use width:100% for the images in the corresponding media query. So your media query should look like this: "@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .employee-image {
        max-width: 200px;
        width:100%;
    }
}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using bootstrap.  In bootstrap you have a helper class called `.img-responsive`.  You can replace `.employee-image` with `.img-responsive` and I think you will get the desired result.

To be more clear - Just add the `img-responsive` class to the desired images.